# Proper way to autowire services to command objects in Grails when constructed inside controller

Tags: spring, grails

I have code like this...

```
@Validateable
class RecipientsCommand {
 ...
 EmailService emailService
 void getEmailEligibleRecipients(Long accountId){
    emailService.loadEligibleEmail(accountId) 
 }
}
```

resource.groovy

```
imports com.test.commands.RecipientsCommand
beans = {
 recipientsCommand(RecipientsCommand){bean -> bean.autowire = true}
}
```

But the service is still always null when I call

```
new RecipientCommand()
```

Since the Command Object seems to be an interface between the views and the controller I am creating it, filling it and passing it to the view. Then I am using it to parse and save data. If I change to...

```
EmailService emailService = new EmailService()
```

Everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto wiring only happens when Grails creates the instance for you.  You can't just `new RecipientCommand()` and expect Spring to be involved in that.  If you retrieve the `recipientsCommand` bean from the Spring application context it will be auto wired and if the `RecipientCommand` is created by the framework and passed as an argument to your controller action, that will also be auto wired.  invoking the `new RecipientCommand()` constructor will result in a new instance being created which is not auto wired.

**EDIT:**

Examples...

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction(RecipientCommand co) {
        // co will already be auto wired
        // this approach does NOT require you to have defined the 
        // recipientsCommand bean in resources.groovy
    }
}

class SomeOtherController {
    def someAction() {
        // rc will be autowired
        // this approach requires you to have defined the 
        // recipientsCommand bean in resources.groovy
        def rc = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('recipientsCommand')
    }
}

class AnotherSomeOtherController {
    def recipientsCommand

    def someAction() {
        // recipientsCommand will be auto wired
        // this approach requires you to have defined the
        // recipientsCommand bean in resources.groovy
    }
}

class YetAnotherController {
    def someAction() {
        // rc will not be autowired
        def rc = new RecipientCommand()
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Does package matter? For example my command is in one package and my controller is in another?

Comment: No, it does not matter if the command object and the controller are in the same package.